# bootstrap responsive behavior only on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make my bootstrap templates only resize on mobile devices and generally have a responsive behavior after a certain width. Meaning for example if on a 15-inch laptop I resize the browser to only half the size it just adds a horizontal scrollbar to the page.

I have tried using container-sm and container-md but it still shrinks when I resize the browser how can I change this behavior. My template is like:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid pl-4 pr-5 pt-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <!-- content -->    
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 order-2">
                  <!-- content -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 order-sm-2 order-sm-2">
                  <!-- content -->
                <div id="#footerPlaceholder"></div>
                </div>       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there any way I can set columns to reshrink after a certain size?

EDIT: I want all elements in the "HTML" tag to resize only after for example screens <600px

Answer (score 0):

You should add **col** before col-sm-3 to fix this issue. like this :

Edited Code :
If I get it right, you should add "col-4" (for example) size for all other devices before your breakpoint device such as small screens.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid pl-4 pr-5 pt-4">
        <div class="row bg-info">
            <div class="col col-4 col-sm-12 bg-info">
              Test  
            </div>
            <div class="col col-4 col-sm-12 order-2 bg-danger">
              Test
            </div>
            <div class="col col-4 col-sm-12 order-sm-2 order-sm-2 bg-success">
              Test
            <div id="#footerPlaceholder"></div>
            </div>       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HI, this will still shrink anything outside "row" tag. Anything inside the body will still shrink if it's not in the row tag such as the navbar

Comment: What do want exactly? please provide more info about the problem with a picture if you can!

Comment: I cannot provide a picture as I can't do it. But For instance on Facebook when you shrink your browser it does not shrink elements and simply adds a horizontal scrollbar. My intention is to add that scrollbar and only shrink elements on small devices such as phones.